# Retrieve event.target in ko function with other variables

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Ok, so in my viewmodels I quite often create functions such as

```
self.updateSomething = function(data, event){

    var theElem = $(event.target); 

    //do stuff with the elem

}
```

That works great, no problems.  The issue I'm having is that I also want to pass in a value to my function.

```
self.updateSomething = function(myVar, data, event){

    var theElem = $(event.target); 

    //do stuff with the theElem AND myVar

}
```

But this doesn't work.  It seems so simple, I'm sure it's just a syntax issue, but I can't figure it out and the GOogle is failing me.  Anyone want to throw me a bone?  Thanks!

Comment: Are those variables going to be constant within the app? If so, you could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751387/knockout-js-binding-a-button-to-an-item-in-a-collection/12751799#12751799) out.

Comment: Can you post a sample call of your `updateSomething` function how it look like in the HMTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried to use the `.bind` function ?

for example, 
in your .html

```
<span data-bind="text: test, click: updateSomething.bind($data,'a variable','another variable') "></span>
```

and in your view model:

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.test = ko.observable('ciao');

    self.updateSomething = function (myVar1, myVar2, data, event) {

        var theElem = $(event.target);

        //do stuff with the theElem AND myVar

    }
}
```

---

I also suggest you an alternative approach, with the usage of a custom binding handler:

in your html:

```
  <span data-bind="myHandler : {var1:'variable1', var2:'variable2'}"></span>
```

in your js file:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myHandler =   {

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var theElem = $(element);
        var variables =valueAccessor();
        var var1 =  variables.var1;

    }
}
```

this second approach permits you to write a more readable and re-usable  code;
Also I personally prefere to leave all access to the DOM (`$(...)` ) in custom binding handlers, for a better separation of concerns. Here you can find an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpezzato/YDDDf/)

Comment: Thank you Francesco, for pointing out that there are other ways to make this happen. A custom binding handler will do the trick in this case.